Repairing gpo-MSI-based installations after file server switches to other host and domain name
Our around 150 Windows 10 based clients in our Server 2019-based AD got their software via software install GPOs, with Install MSIs available under \\oldhost.olddomain.local\installpath\.
Some days ago we finished our move to a new AD, newdomain.local, changing also the system name to newhost. To keep GPO-based installations up and running, we made sure to use ADSI edit as per this Microsoft article in order edit existing install GPOs to reflect the new installation paths.
Problem: after doing the host/domain change existing software could not be upgraded/removed, since the system remembers the last location software was installed from (AFAIK, this information is stored under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\<package ID>\SourceList\Net). Trying to repair/change an existing package throws "The feature you are trying to access ..." error.
So far, we've tried adding a olddomain.local zone in our new AD and created a DNS CNAME entry in it named oldhost, in order for oldhost.olddomain.local to point to newhost.newdomain.local (note: the installpath has remained the same). This doesn't work though.
Is modifying the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\<package ID>\SourceList\Net a viable solution (fiddling with anything Installer-related is generally not advised).
How would one go about resolving this situation?
